# cannot open a file whose name is stored in another file (bash)

Tags: bash

I have a file name PATH storing the path of two files as

```
A "/home/ubuntu/abc"
B "/home/ubuntu/test"
```

now, when i run a command like `cat "/home/ubuntu/test"` it shows the content of the file test
but if i do `VAR=$(grep "B" < PATH | cut -d' ' -f2)` and then `cat $B` it shows error:

> No such file or directory

What is happening?

Comment: echo the contents of `$B` you will see that it contains the quotes.

Comment: `echo $B` would probably answer your question. never assume your code is actually working.

Comment: yeah i have done echo $B its same "/home/ubuntu/test"

Comment: root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu/AUV# cat "/home/ubuntu/AUV/test"
nav test
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu/AUV# echo $B
"/home/ubuntu/AUV/test"
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu/AUV# cat $B
cat: "/home/ubuntu/AUV/test": No such file or directory
this i have copied the output prom terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `"` as  delimiter in the cut command.

```
$ cat ri
A "/home/ubuntu/abc"
B "/home/file/to/open"
$ var=$(grep "B" < PATH | cut -d'"' -f2)
$ cat "$var"
```